# PHP Order Image stack

Tags: php

I have an application that stacks images in a certain order.
Where the order is the same i need it to be random, when the page is generated.

```
Order, image_name 
[1, image1]
[1, image2]
[2, image3]
[3, image4]
```

The first time the page is generated, the slide shows;

```
Order, image_name 
[1, image1]
[1, image2]
[2, image3]
[3, image4]
```

The second time the page is generated the slide shows:

```
Order, image_name 
[1, image2]
[1, image1]
[2, image3]
[3, image4]
```

The third time the page is generated the slide shows:

```
Order, image_name 
[1, image1]
[1, image2]
[2, image3]
[3, image4]
```

I have in the db a order field, and a filename field.

(edit) is there a way to do that with a single select??

Comment: Don't use the order id. Get all the images and use [PHP Shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)?

Comment: but that's not what i need. For example imagine that i want that images to remain in the first images of a slide.

Comment: Whut?!? Images in the first images of a slide.

Comment: slide of five images ( (order:1)image 1, (order:1)image 2, (order:2)image 3, (order:3)image 4, (order:4)image 5). the seconde time the page is generated i get: ( (order:1)image 2, (order:1)image 1, (order:2)image 3, (order:3)image 4, (order:4)image 5).

Comment: So this is what you want or this is what is happening? You want that where order = 1 the images would rotate?

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the SQL:

```
ORDER BY `Order` ASC,RAND()
```

It will order by `Order` field, and any which are the same, it will use RAND() as it's secondary sort.

Comment: almost. With RAND() it is never certain. Some time the first images is correct but it is not certain. I want always that.

Comment: @TiagoMoutinho I think you may need to revise your question. You said "When the order is the same I need it to be random" and that's what my code will do, random.

Answer (score 0):

perhaps using ORDER BY RAND() in your MySQL query?

Comment: that wont help me. where the order is the same it has to random to a kind of FIFO( first in first out), like a rotation thing;